# Null pointer exception when accessing Google Calendar

Tags: java, android, debugging, calendar

I am writing a android app that need to **insert event to Google Calendar**. I run my app in my two android phone and thay are all success. However, some crash reports from others are received. They have **null pointer exception** in the last line of the following code.

(BTW, I have already handled two different URIs of google calendar by following [Is there a way to access the calendar's entries without using gdata-java-client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846942/is-there-a-way-to-access-the-calendars-entries-without-using-gdata-java-client))

**Entire source code file: http://gonow.no-ip.org/hkpl/GoogleCalendar.java**

I call function addEvent in another class by this

```
GoogleCalendar.addEvent(getContentResolver(),EVENT_TITLE,CONTENT);
```

Extracted:

```
ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
event.put("title", title);
event.put("description", description);
event.put("calendar_id",calId);      
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);     
long start = cal.getTime().getTime();
event.put("dtstart", start);        
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);  
long end = cal.getTime().getTime();        
event.put("dtend", end);        
event.put("hasAlarm",1); 
event.put("allDay", 1);           
Uri newEvent = cr.insert(Uri.parse(calanderEventURL), event); <-- exception here
```

---

Crash report here

> java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
>   doInBackground() at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200) at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1328) at
>   android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:160)
>   at
>   android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:114)
>   at
>   android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:408)
>   at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:604) at
>   ming.hkpl.GoogleCalendar.addEvent(GoogleCalendar.java:93)

Comment: What's on line 93? Maybe you can add line numbers to your code.

Comment: As I mentioned above, it is at the last line of the code
ie. Uri newEvent = cr.insert(Uri.parse(calanderEventURL), event);
Thank :)

Comment: i'm confused.  doesn't this just mean that cr is null?  sorry if i am missing something obvious!

Comment: Sorry, let me upload my entire source code

Comment: @Bear: Please use the Google Calendar GData API to modify a user's Google Calendar.

Comment: Thx, but I can't find a complete turoial using google data api to access google calendar in android

Answer (score 1):

In general, use the following process:

- Find the line number of the failure in the bottom of the stack trace with the company namespace (ming.hkpl.GoogleCalendar.addEvent)
- Go to the line number of the file mentioned in the stack trace in an IDE or text editor

  - Add a breakpoint
  - Compile the code
  - Run jdb
    OR
- Add a print statement to the previous line, printing the variable referenced in the line that throws an error. For example:

  ```
  System.out.println("Hi");
  System.out.println(driver);
  ```
- Rebuild the code

**References**

- [Debugging Exceptions within your App | CodePath Android Cliffnotes](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Debugging-Exceptions-within-your-App)
- [Embedded print Statements != Debugging | Dr Dobb's](http://www.drdobbs.com/article/print?articleId=240148855&siteSectionName=architecture-and-design)
- [How do you reproduce bugs that occur sporadically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515903/how-do-you-reproduce-bugs-that-occur-sporadically)
- [How do you fix a bug you can't replicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268373/how-do-you-fix-a-bug-you-cant-replicate)
- [Effective Methods for Debugging Concurrent Software (pdf)](https://parasol.tamu.edu/~jeff/academic/phdThesis.pdf)
- [jdb](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jdb.html)
- [Debugging Java Programs using JDB | PACKT Books](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/debugging-java-programs-using-jdb)